# Energy of pulling a polymer

Tags: statistical-mechanics, polymers

When we have a polymer of $N$ monomers with position vectors $\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2, \ldots, \vec{r}_N$, pulled by a force $\vec{f}$, why is the potential energy then given by:

$U = \left( \vec{r}_N - \vec{r}_1 \right) \cdot \vec{f}$

Because I thought that energy was force times displacement, but $\vec{r}_N - \vec{r}_1$ does not represent the displacement from the average size of a polymer without a force? It represents the total distance between the end points, not the displacement by the force?

Thanks in advance for the future replies!

Comment: Hint: the energy of the $i$th monomer is $U_i = (\vec{r_{i+1}} - \vec{r_i})\cdot \vec{f}$. Sum over the energies.

Comment: But why? My point was that I thought that energy is force times displacement, while $\vec{r_{i+1}} - \vec{r_{i}}$ is not the displacement, it is the total distance between the monomers. The displacement would be $\vec{r_{i+1}} - \vec{r_{i}} - \langle \vec{r_{i+1}} - \vec{r_{i}} \rangle$.

Comment: I believe $\vec{r_i}$ is the starting point of the $i$th monomer, not the midpoint.

Comment: What does that even mean? The vectors point from the center of the coordinate system to the midpoint of the monomer.

Comment: If that were true, your equation for $U$ would fail with $N = 1$.